# Show more / less button with transition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, show-hide

First, sorry for my potato english. Also it's my first question here.

So. I work with **Vuejs** but I dont think it's important in this case. I have html string that looks for example like this -

```
<h1><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></h1><p>Some long text and the image - <img src="some-img-src"></p>
```

it's generated based on what author of the post will write.
If post is too long, on page load it should display only few lines and there should be button Show more / less.

I did my solution where I used height with transition, where initial height is about 500px and then it is computed with clientHeight. But problem are images, sometimes they are here, sometimes not, height of images is always different too, so they will be cut in half sometimes or make text to be cut in half on the last line, when it's folded. I tried to use line-clamping too and it somehow worked but then I have no idea how to make it with **transition**, which is important here.

Is it even possible?

edit: Here - [jsfiddle.net/sm2xLj5v/9](https://jsfiddle.net/sm2xLj5v/9/) (Not sure why mounted is not working so i removed v-if on `<a>` tag, but overall its the same.

Comment: can you share your working solution ? we will update as you want ? please sue code snippet.

Comment: If the text + image is above 500px, would it be fine to hide the entire image and just show a "display more" button?

Comment: Here - https://jsfiddle.net/sm2xLj5v/9/  (Not sure why mounted is not working so i removed v-if on <a> tag, but overall its the same.

Comment: Yes sure it will be fine to hide it :)

Answer (score 0):

you should be create an array to store active items.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showMores: [],
      items: [
        {id: 21, content: 'test<br>hellow<br>world'}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showMore(item) {
      if(this.showMores.indexOf(item.id)===-1) {
        this.showMores.push(item.id)
      } else {
        this.showMores.splice(this.showMores.indexOf(item.id), 1)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.item {height: 22px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 20px}
.item.more {height: auto}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item" :class="{more: (showMores.indexOf(item.id)!==-1)}" v-for="item in items">
      <button @click="showMore(item)">More</button><span v-html="item.content"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
          return {
            isshow:true,
            items: [
              {id: 21, content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, ex quisquam aperiam si delectus molestias fugit  dolores animi excepturi necessitatibus'}
            ]
          }
        },
        methods: {
          showMore() {
            this.isshow = !this.isshow
          }
        }
      })
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
 
 <div id="app">
        <p v-if=isshow>{{items[0].content.substr(0, 20)}} <button @click="showMore()">Read more</button></p>
        <p v-else>{{items[0].content}}  <button @click="showMore()">Show less</button></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope this will work for you. Now you can play with this logic. Or you can share your code what you have tried.

Comment: Ooh looks good, thank you! But is it possible to make it with transition? (Slow slide down/up) ?

Comment: There are different ways to do sliding implementation. You can use jquery https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_slideup_slidedown . But I ll recommend to use the third  party plugin. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slide-up-down. Here is the exampls. https://codepen.io/danieldiekmeier/pen/YapGWq

Answer (score 0):

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    showAlert : false,
  },
  computed : {
    text () {
        return this.showAlert ? "Hide" : "Show";
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
        this.showAlert = !this.showAlert;
    }
  }
})
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="app">
  <button class="btn btn-info" @click="toggle">
    {{text}}
  </button>
  <transition name="slide">
    <div class="mt-4" v-if="showAlert">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.slide-enter-active {
  animation: slide-in 1s ease-out forwards;
}

.slide-leave-active {
  animation: slide-out 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

See the above snippet if this serves your purpose or not.

my js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/shubhambattoo/god4se5k/6/

you can read about transitions in vuejs : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html